# Is there a Python pool for individual iteration in loops?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

Is there any way to Python pool an iteration itself?

For example, I tried the following:

```py
def x():
    for i in range(10):
        ...
```

The number of iterations is 10 (0 to 9), can we create a pool which creates 10 separate processes for iteration `i=0`, `i=1`, ... `i=9`?

Answer (score 0):

The language does not have it in that simple form. But I remember seeing a small package that would provide an iterator for just that once.  I will try to find it,but I doubt it is still maintained.

Here it is: https://github.com/npryce/python-parallelize
And present in Pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-parallelize/1.0.0.0

If it works, it may be a matter of 'unmainained due to being complete' - just test your stuff - a lot.